# drop_sel does not accept slice

Tags: python, python-xarray

Say I have an xarray DataArray. One of the Dimensions is a time dimension:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

time = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '2017-12-01', freq='MS')
time = xr.DataArray(time, dims=('time',), coords={'time':time})

da = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(len(time)), dims=('time',), coords={'time':time})
```

Now if I only want the years from 1990 to 2000, what I can do is easy:

```
da.sel(time=slice('1990', '2000'))
```

But what if I want to **drop** these years? I want the data for all years **except** those.

```
da.drop_sel(time=slice('1990', '2000'))
```

fails with

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

What's going on? What's the proper way to do that?

At the moment, I'm creating a new DataArray:

```
tdrop = da.time.sel(time=slice('1990', '2000'))
da.drop_sel(time=tdrop)
```

But that seems unnecessary convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`where`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html#xarray-dataarray-where) with the `drop` optional parameter set to `True` to filter on the year? Using the example below, the data with `1990 <= year <= 2000` would be dropped.

```py
da = da.where((da["time.year"] < 1990) | (da["time.year"] > 2000), drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to add that I only recently noticed that the `drop_sel` method is quite young at this point, so maybe the functionality will still be added. Anyway, here's your bounty.